# Backbone.js: model save request has current url path prefixed

Tags: backbone.js

In my backbone.js, when I call `model.save()` the url gets the current URL path prefixed in it.

Suppose my model is:

```
RegisterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: ''
    },
    url: 'register/confirm'
});
```

My router is defined like:

```
AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'signup/confirm/:key': 'confirm'
    },

    confirm: function(key) {
         var mod1 = new RegisterModel({key:key});
         mod1.save();
    }
});
```

Now if I understand the ajax request should be sent to

`register/confirm`

Instead it is sent to...

`signup/confirm/register/confirm`

What could be leading to this? Could this be because of `pushstate:true` that I am using to start Backbone.History???

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState:true});
```

I need this because I don't want to use hashed URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use URLs that are relative to the site's root? In that case you could try:

```
RegisterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: ''
    },
    url: '/register/confirm'
});
```